# How to block specific websites in a specific browser?

Tags: browser, blocking, hosts-file

I want to block Youtube in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Chromium, is there a way to do this? The only solution I found is adding this to the hosts file

```
0.0.0.1 youtube.com    
0.0.0.1 www.youtube.com
```

but that will block it in all browsers.
If only you could put some if (!chromium) in the host file.

edit:
Solution to my problem in the end was a creating webserver through Web Server for Chrome where i have a json file thats linked to a chrome and mozzila extension where the extension looks at that json file through the server if it should or should not block websites at that moment.

Comment: *"If only you could put some if (!chromium) in the hosts file."* - The [hosts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file only maps hostnames to IP addresses (as in your example). There are (literally) no other options, excluding comments.

Comment: Since you have found a solution, please consider self-answering to explain that solution in additional detail.

Answer (score 2):

Install an adblock plugin for each browser and add the domain in its custom adblock list to block it.

Alternatively, search for a plugin that specifically blocks a website.

Comment: The problem is, im using a bash script to blocks system applications too, for a certain time interval, so that means i have to find a way to enable/disable extensions via bash script.

Comment: Why can't you just use the browser's built in functionality to add the extensions?